# OP linking to personal blog instead of official documentation

Tags: discussion

I answered this question: [Is nameof() evaluated at compile-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26573102/885318).

While this is a completely valid question, the explanation of what actually is `nameof()` directs to the OP's personal blog. This seems somewhat clickbaity, especially when it's about a future C# feature and has the potential of coming up in many future searches.

So, is that OK? Should the question be edited for a more official source (like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx))?

Comment: It's okay as long as the link is properly attributed. Which is isn't. The OP also doesn't include any code in it's problem statement. Plenty of reason to DV, imo.

Comment: @Cerbrus What do you mean by properly attributed?

Comment: _"[link] (links to my blog)"_ Basically, the OP should mention that that's his blog.

Comment: The question looks like a disguised attempt at advertising the blog.

Comment: IMO, yes. The link should be edited to point to an official resource.

Comment: "A disguised attempt at advertising the blog". Wow, people sure are quick to jump to conclusions around here. Btw, thanks for the edit. The only "official" description of nameof() I could find was the example in the PDF in the language features page.

Comment: I'd caution about DV without a comment as to why. I would have no freaking clue what was wrong with my question in this scenario, and I am sure the same is true for others. If you shouldn't link to a personal blogs, great, just make it explicit _why_, as it is not always the case.

Comment: @stevebot I think an edit is the correct response, not a DV.

Comment: This thread proves to be a good way to attract an unreasonable number of downvotes to that question. Since OP (@Gigi) has quite a number of questions and answers already, I'd investigate those first before jumping to conclusions. And if there are so little sources about the subject, and OP has written a blog about it (also helping others), I think it's pretty rude that he got so many downvotes without even a single comment as to why. I think SO overreacted today.

Comment: @Gigi I apologise if you included that link in good faith, perhaps I should have asked first before replacing the link. The downvotes are unfortunate, it seems some people downvoted because of this situation instead of voting on how good/useful the question is.

Comment: @GolezTrol This thread only provides attention. The downvotes came from the SO community and the sympathy upvotes as well. Just like the DVs this post is getting. If I wasn't the one answering the question I would probably go ahead and edit, there's no need for any conclusions, but I'm not impartial.

Comment: At the end the OP is better off, not worse. The only question left is which link to use to make the question better, and help more people in the future?

Comment: No problem. I originally linked to my blog because I thought it constituted a good example of the operator's usage, but any official reference is better, so please leave the official link.

Comment: @Gigi Great, the system works! (and i want to make clear that it's a good question which I immediately upvoted and never removed it)

Comment: To be honest I would have preferred if people voted based on the usefulness of the question rather than any underlying motive (perceived or otherwise). The link could have simply been edited out or replaced (as it has been). I saw no reason for either downvotes or sympathy upvotes.

Comment: @Gigi of course. But you can't control people. At least I can't.

Comment: @Gigi Honestly I preferred your blog post. There was no need to change it just a note say it's from your personal blog would have been sufficient. Sometimes people can be a bit heavy handed around  here.

Comment: @Gigi http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275415/op-linking-to-personal-blog-instead-of-official-documentation#comment110860_275416

Comment: Given the feedback, I have taken out the link and put relevant links (including the one to my blog, properly attributed) in an edit to make everything clear. I tried to find additional links which may be informative but there wasn't much on the topic. If anyone has a problem with the edit (perhaps you don't like me linking to my blog or something), feel free to edit over it.

Comment: You should include screenshots to the threads within your thread itself, the links may soon become obsolete if they are handled by community attention as you put them up.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with providing a link to your own blog post that readers can follow for additional information, so long as the post is suitable without the reader needing to follow the link.  It is also important to follow all of the [self-promotion guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), such as the fact that the post needs to disclose the fact that it is your own blog post (if that is in fact the case) when posting the question, that the link actually be relevant to the post, etc.

Of course, when evaluating a post you are free to evaluate the decision as to what links to include.  If you feel that the links someone includes in a post are of lower quality than, for example, the official documentation, then you are more than welcome to take that into consideration when voting on how helpful the post is.  (This is really more for answers than for questions.)  Editing the post so that it links to a resource that you simply like better than what the author choose is not a valid edit.

Answer (score 10):

It's perfectly valid to link to a personal blog discussing a topic rather than the official source, *especially* if the personal blog has more detail than the official documentation, or if it discusses some specific aspect of the topic that the question is about more than the official documentation. In this case, the blog adds more value and context to the question than the official documentation does.

Another concern is about personal blogs is that they are far more volatile and subject to link-rot than official documentation. So even in these cases, it doesn't hurt to also link to the official documentation.

As long as the link is relevant and doesn't violate the guidelines [Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275438/1715579) mentions, I would leave it. Adding a more relevant or useful resource to a question or answer will likely benefit future users.

Comment: Your qualification is not in fact a valid requirement.  If someone wants to link to their own blog post describing something they can.  The fact that there is official documentation on the subject doesn't mean they're forced to use it.

Comment: @Servy I see your point, let me rephrase

Comment: I see a personal blog as a bit less trusthworthy than the official documentation and would probably link to the official documentation too, even if there is less information. Don't get me wrong, some blogs might be excellent, but surely not all.

Answer (score -3):

I've replaced the link with a link to the spec, which comes from [http://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language feature status](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20feature%20status):

> http://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/570551

Comment: I wouldn't have changed it just added a note to say the link is to a personal blog post. Personally I found the blog post very informative and a lot easier to read then the codeplex formatted page.

Comment: It is an entirely invalid edit to change someone else's link to point somewhere that you simply like better.

Comment: @Servy Does seem a bit heavy handed.

Comment: @Servy context matters. It wasn't a case of simply liking another link better, it was a case of mistakenly thinking that the goal of the question was self-promotion.

Comment: @Stijn Did you happen to notice the link you changed it to is the one used in l3arnon's answer? That makes it look more like the OP didn't even read what they linked to... Unless I'm missing something here, it also looks bad on the OP of the SO question.

Comment: @Kendra No, I didn't notice that. Perhaps it's better to just revert my edit, but I'll leave that up to OP.

Comment: @Stijn 1) *Mistakenly* is a key point there.  This is clearly not a case of inappropriate self-promotion 2) It's not the appropriate way to deal with self-promotion when you do come across it.  If the link is relevant in context then it should have been edited to indicate the link is the author's own blog; if it's not relevant to the question it should have been removed entirely.  A flag would also be appropriate for suspected inappropriate self-promotion.  Changing the links to a link you simply like better is not an acceptable response.

Comment: Could prompt a new Meta question: *Should we be replacing links with official ones if the link links to unofficial documentation?'

Comment: @cybermonkey Seriously? We can't link to decent, unofficial articles? You should see the quality of some official documentation, e.g. [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx). Just a one-liner, and not even an example. I'd choose a random guy's blog post over this any day.